# Countability of minimal and maximal elements.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, order-theory, cardinals

Let $A=P(N)-\{\emptyset,N\}$ and $\subset$ is a partial order on A. Show that the set of minimal elements and maximal elements is countable.

My solution was to show that:

Set of minimal elements $=\{\{n\}:n\in N\}$

Sketch: if $X$ is minimal and $|X|\geq2$ then $\{f(0)\}\subset X$ where $f:2\rightarrow X$ is a one to one function. If $|X|=1 $ then the only proper subset would be $\emptyset$

Set of maximal elements $=\{N-\{n\}:n\in N\}$

Sketch: if $X$ is maximal and $|Q|\geq2$ where $Q\subseteq N$ then $N-Q\subset N- \{f(0)\}\subset X$ where $f:2\rightarrow Q$ is a one to one function. If $|Q|=1 $ then the only proper superset would be $N$

Hence both sets are countable with the obvious bijection with N

i.e. $n\rightarrow \{n\} and$ $n\rightarrow\{N-\{n\}\}$

Comment: f is pointless.  If A subser N is a multipoint set, then some x in A.  Thus {x} proper subset A.  Whence all multipoint sets are not minimal.

Comment: $a\in A$ is minimal iff $a=\{n\}$ for some $n\in \Bbb N$ and $b\in A$ is maximal iff $b=\Bbb N\setminus \{n\}$ for some $n\in \Bbb N.$